# MVC user created values -- Is reflection my only hope?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to determine if a controller exists before attempting to return the View?  In my scenerio, my action value in my URL represents a user created value, and the id represents the controller. i.e.

```
http://mysite.com/systems/WIN1234/Configure
```

...where **WIN1234** is dynamically routed to the **Configure** action.  Because I would like to keep my URLs completely hackable, I would like to determine if Configure exists before...

```
return View(action)
```

...where action is my passed in string containing **Configure**.

The first thing that pops into my head is looking at the assembly using reflection, but before I go that far, and because of my wet ears in MVC, I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to make this determination.  i.e.  ...something like:

```
if(DoesControllerExist(action)) return View(action)
```

...where DoesControllerExist is a built in MVC function.

Any of you experts have any ideas?

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I get you completely correct, but is this your situation:

```
http://mysite.com/systems/WIN1234/Configure
```

Should go to

```
public class SystemsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Configure(string theValue)  //<== This would be "WIN123" in your example
    {
        return View(theValue);
    }
}
```

Where you want to make sure that the following view exists:

```
YourMVCProject
  |
  +- Views
      |
      +- Systems
           |
           +- theValue.aspx
```

In that case you can use:

```
private bool ViewExists(string name)
{
    return ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, name, null).View != null;
}
```

and alter your action to:

```
public ActionResult Configure(string theValue)  //<== This would be "WIN123" in your example
{
    if(ViewExists(theValue))
    {
        return View(theValue);
    }
    return View(fallBackView);
}
```

*Disclaimer: all freehand code*

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confused as to how the routing system works.

A URL is mapped to a controller and action.  If there's no matching controller and action, you'll get an HTTP 404.

Thankfully, URL routes (and of course controllers) are testable so you may want to simply [write unit tests for your routing configuration](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/17/testing-routes-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx).

On another note, you probably do not want multiple URLs mapping to the same content without issuing an HTTP 301 (permanently moved) since it works against your PageRank.

Comment: The routing portion isn't the issue, my custom routes are set up correctly to look at my new URL structure.  I simply do not want the 404 to exist when I can intercept the bad request and direct it to the appropriate View. :)